# How to check if an item inside jCarousel clip is in the viewable clip area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

Hi I have a jCarousel that has 10 items, and the clip only shows 3 items.

I want to check if a certain item that has a specific class `myItem` is in the clip view or hidden outside the clip.

I tried to use `if ($('.myItem:visible').length == 0) {}` but apparently this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the itemVisibleInCallback which is called when an item becomes visible. here's a little example:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/vTSh2/2/